# CSS Style Select Active Menu Item Differently Than Others on Hover

Tags: css, menu, joomla

The following HTML is created by Joomla 1.7 for the menu of a site I'm working on:

```
<ul class="menu-tabbed-horiz">

<li class="item-435 current active parent">
    <a class="firstmenuitem" href="/joomla/" >Home</a>
</li>
<li class="item-467">
    <a href="/joomla/index.php/menu2" >Menu 2</a>
</li>
<li class="item-468">
    <a href="/joomla/index.php/memu3" >Menu 3</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

Via CSS, I'm styling this menu. For example, I style the menu item that the mouse is hovering over like this: `.menu-tabbed-horiz a:hover`. The active one can be styled like so: `.menu-tabbed-horiz .current  a`.

This works without problem, but now I would like to style a menu item differently when it is the current one and hovered on than when it is just hovered on. Something like `.menu-tabbed-horiz a:hover && !.current`, but that obviously does not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, Fabian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, then you're looking for something like this:

```
.menu-tabbed-horiz .current a:hover { /*Hovered and current*/ }
.menu-tabbed-horiz a:hover { /*Hovered (all)*/ }
```

This should work because the first selector is more specific than the second and will therefore be applied to elements with `.current` instead of the second selector.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/RhXPC/5/) of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this kind of thing directly.  The solution is to define the "non-current" style for .menu-tabbed-horiz li, and the "current" style for .menu-tabbed-horiz li.active.

The second style is more specific than the first, so it will take precedence whenever both styles are present.  The first style will be applied for all .menu-tabbed-horiz elements that don't have the .current class.